# SQL Query to get different records from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have two tables in my DB,One is User and contains user_id, second is user_follower and this contain user_id and follower_id(user_id of other user).
i want to get user list but don't want to get those user in it that is already in user_follower table for current user.
for example i have user_id 1 and want to get user list for this, i want all user that is is not in user_followers as follower.
can some one help me in this.
please.

i tried

```
select user_id from user
MINUS
select user_id from user_followers
```

but i get error on this , it is not supported by msql

Comment: what did you tried so far? can you show us some code?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @rsz can you see now my question, i edited

Comment: @RiggsFolly i tried this , but i am getting error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sub query in where clouse for filter data from multiple table

```
SELECT t.user_id from user t
     WHERE NOT IN(SELECT uf.user_id FROM user_followers uf
                 WHERE uf.user_id = t.user_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Query,  It Will help You

```
SELECT `user`.`user_id` FROM `user`  WHERE `user`.`user_id` NOT IN( select `user_id` from `user_followers`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`.

```
select U.user_id from user U
INNER JOIN user_followers UF ON U.user_id = UF.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
$users_list = $this->db->select("u.*",FALSE)
    ->from("user u")
    ->join("user_follower uf","u.user_id != uf.user_id")
    ->get();

//The query is:
//SELECT u.* FROM user u INNER JOIN user_follower uf ON (u.user_id != uf.user_id)
```

To view the results:

```
 print_r($users_list->result_array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Sub Query

```
select user_id from `user` where user_id not in (select user_id from user_followers)
```